# Unable to Create Common Data Service DB in Default Environment Power Apps

Tags: dynamics-365, powerapps, common-data-service

I am unable to create a new Common Data Service Database in my Power Apps default environment. Please see the error text below.

> It looks like you don't have permission to use the Common Data Service
>   in this environment. Switch to a different environment, or create your
>   own.

Which as I understand I should be able to create after the Microsoft Business Application October 2018 update as listed in the article available at following link.

https://community.dynamics.com/365/b/dynamicscitizendeveloper/archive/2018/10/17/demystifying-dynamics-365-and-powerapps-environments-part-1

Also when I try to create a Common Data Service app in my default environment, I encounter following error.

> The data did not load correctly. Please try again.
>
> The environment 'Default-57e1485d-1197-4afd-b792-5c423ab508d9' is not
>   linked to a new CDS 2.0 instance. The operation 'ListInstanceMetadata'
>   is forbidden for unlinked environments

Moreover I am unable to see the default environment on https://admin.powerapps.com/environments, I can only see the Sandbox environment there.

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Someone else faced a similar issue and I read in one of the threads about deleting the browser cache and trying it again or trying it in a different browser resolved the issue. Could you try these first level steps and check if you still have these issues?
Ref: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Common-Data-Service-for-Apps/Default-Environment-Error-on-CDS/m-p/233582#M1281

Also, for your permission error ref: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Common-Data-Service-for-Apps/Common-Data-Service-Business-Flows/td-p/142053

I have not validated these findings. But as these answers are from MS and PowerApps team, hope it helps!